# android- extract metadata from doxc, apache tika ,poi, groupdocs,

Tags: android, apache-poi, docx, apache-tika

i need to extract metadata from docx files,
when i add this to build.gradle of new project:

```
implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-core:2.8.0'
implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-parsers-standard-package:2.8.0'
```

**this : implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-parsers-standard-package:2.8.0'**
leads to build failure.
the errors in shortly:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform jackson-core-2.15.0.jar (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users.......
> 2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.15.0\12f334a1dc9c6d2854c43ae314024dde8b3ad572\jackson-core-2.15.0.jar.

Failed to transform fastdoubleparser-0.8.0.jar (ch.randelshofer:fastdoubleparser:0.8.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> Execution failed for

2.
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform jackson-core-2.15.0.jar (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-java-res, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: s-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.15.0\12f334a1dc9c6d2854c43ae314024dde8b3ad572\jackson-core-2.15.0.jar.
> > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.15.0\12f334a1dc9c6d2854c43ae314024dde8b3ad572\jackson-core-2.15.0.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 63. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Suggestions:

```
     > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
```

> Failed to transform jackson-core-2.15.0.jar (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

how solve this? thanks

**i tried to extract metadata with two more libraries:**

i tried to import groupdocs library :
implementation 'com.**groupdocs:groupdocs-parser**:23.2'

but build fails with :
** 1. **  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

2:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.groupdocs:groupdocs-parser:23.2.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/groupdocs/groupdocs-parser/23.2/groupdocs-parser-23.2.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/groupdocs/groupdocs-parser/23.2/groupdocs-parser-23.2.pom

Comment: try upgrading jackson to v2.15.1 - there is a fix for https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/999 - jackson 2.15.1 has a couple of issues but hopefully they won't affect you

Comment: I suggest you also contact the maintainers of 'Jetifier' because it seems to be struggling with the fact that jackson-core 2.15.x is a multi-release jar which is  (https://openjdk.org/jeps/238 and see https://www.baeldung.com/java-multi-release-jar)